# A difficult question about Runge-Kutta method and Euler's method

Tags: numerical-methods, totient-function, runge-kutta-methods

[image]

I found this question extremely difficult... Especially part b. 
For part b, I've tried several times. Is it correct that we need to use Taylor expansion to solve it?

Since $e'(t) = f(...) + u'(t)$, we just use Lagrange polynomial interpolation to find the $u(t)$, and then take the derivative of u, so that we could have $u'(t)$.

And then for $e_n+1 = e_n(==0) + h*(f(...) ) - h * u'(t_n)$. Then we go back to the $u'(t)$ function, and calculate for $u'(tn)$?

After we have $e_n+1$, we could calculage $e_n+2$, like $e_n+2 = e_n+1 + h *f(...) - h * u'(t_n+1)$?

Is it a way that could work?

Thanks for the help!